# bash to ensure all folders are created from file using matching line

Tags: bash

In the below `bash` I am trying to ensure that all folders (represented by $folders) in a given directory are created. In the file `f1` the main folder will be there somewhere (will be multiple main folders).
When that folder is found (represented by $S5) the contents of `$2` printed to `$STRING`. A `newline` always separates a block and if `$STRING` is the same as `$folders` then that folder is already created in the directory and it can be skipped (this will be the case most of the time). If `$STRING` is not the same as `$folders` then the missing is created in the directory. The code seems to work as expected until the comparison and the actual match is portion below is not working as expected and prints and makes the wrong folders.  Thank you :).

**f1**

```
yyy_009 00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx
yyy_004 00-0011-xxx-xxx-xxx
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-200_yyyyyyy

zzzz_0000 00-3333-zz-zz
zzzz_0005 00-1111-xxx-xxx
zzzz_0003 00-2222-yyy-yy
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123-v5.6_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxxx
```

**bash**

```
DIR=/home/user/Desktop/new
for RDIR in "$DIR"/R_2019* ; do  ## # matching "R_2019*" to operate on desired directory and expand
  S5=${RDIR##*/}  ## store run with no path as S5
  TRIMSTR=${RDIR%%-v5.6*}  ## trim folder match in RDIR from -v5.6 and store in TRIMSTR
    mv "$RDIR" "$TRIMSTR"  ## move trimmed folder to directory
  cd "$TRIMSTR"
   folders=`ls -d *[0-9]*/`  ## list folders
    STRING=$(awk -F '\n' -v RS="" -v ref="$S5" '$0 ~ ref {print $2}' "$DIR"/f1)
  if [[ $folders != $STRING* ]] ## only execute folder on mis-match
   then
     mkdir -p "$TRIMSTR"/$STRING/folder
  fi
done
```

**desired**

```
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123
  00-1111-xxx-xxx
    folder
  00-2222-yyy-yy
    folder
  00-3333-zz-zz
    folder
```

`set -x`

```
+ for rdir in '"$dir"/R_2019*'
+ s5=R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123- 
v5.6_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxxx
+ trimstr=/home/cmccabe/folder/R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123
+ mv /home/cmccabe/folder/R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123- 
v5.6_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxxx 
/home/cmccabe/folder/R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123
+ cd /home/cmccabe/folder/R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123
++ ls --color=auto -d 00-1111-xxx-xxx/ 00-2222-yyy-yy/
+ folders='00-1111-xxx-xxx/
00-2222-yyy-yy/'
++ awk -F '\n' -v RS= -v ref=R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000-123- 
v5.6_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxxx '$0 ~ ref {print $2}' 
/home/cmccabe/folder/f1
+ string='zzzz_0005 00-1111-xxx-xxx'
+ [[ 00-1111-xxx-xxx/
00-2222-yyy-yy/ != zzzz_0005 00-1111-xxx-xxx* ]]
+ mkdir -p '/home/cmccabe/folder/R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_x0-00000- 
123/zzzz_0005 00-1111-xxx-xxx/folder'
```

Comment: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's on SO but applies to your problem so, so much. Are `00-1111-xxx-xxx` etc. real names that reproduce the problem? The directory structure is for `/path/to/…`, then the script operates on `/home/user/…`; what? Parsing `ls` is wrong. Unquoted `$STRING` after `mkdir` is wrong. Uppercase local variables are bad practice. The test looks weird. Why not `[ -d … ]` as the test? Finally: to "ensure that all folders are created" just `mkdir -p` them; `man mkdir` says `no error if existing`, no existence test required.

Comment: Yes, the code runs and will produce results, just not the desired. The `$DIR` variable needs to be changed to the path that the main folder and `f1` resides in... I will up date the post with  `set -x`. Thank you :).`